# Change default RandomForestClassifier's "score" function when fitting the model?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I perform the fitting operation using `RandomForestClassifier` from `sklearn`:

```
clf.fit(X_train,y_train,sample_weight=weight)
```

I don't know **how to change the evaluation metric**, which I assume it's simply accuracy here.

I'm asking this because I've seen that with the [XGBOOST](http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python/python_intro.html) package you can precisely specify this metric. Example:

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric="auc", eval_set=[(X_eval, y_eval)])
```

So, my question is: could I do the same with `RandomForestClassifier` from `sklearn`. I need to base my performance on [AUC](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/AUC) metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what I'm doing so far is to wrap the classifier into a `GridSearchCV` where I can specify the scoring method.

So: `GS = grid_search.GridSearchCV(forest_clf, parameters, scoring='roc_auc',verbose=10)` works for me.

*But I'm open to any suggestions if that's possible to be performed from the classifier itself, or any theoretical explanations if that's not a correct approach.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the metric used by the score method of RandomForestClassifier.

But this code should give you the auc:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
roc_auc_score(y_eval, clf.predict_proba(X_eval))
```

Comment: Mind you providing some context to your answer please?

Comment: Sorry. I think brief answers are often appreciated but this might have been a bit too brief.

Answer (score 0):

As Guiem Bosch mentioned, the best way to get a different scoring method is by GridSearchCV. Indeed `RandomForestClassifier` has accuracy as scoring method.

However, I am not quite sure as to what you mean exactly with your question. You can always check the classifier's other scoring methods by running different scoring functions on the test set after the classifier is fitted by importing them from `sklearn.metrics`.

Be cautious here though:

- With `GridSearchCV` and `scoring=['roc_auc', 'recall']` etc. you will get the best classifier for the grid parameters, for each scoring metric you specify. For example, you will get the best classifier (set of hyperparameters) for 'roc_auc' score or for 'recall' score, based on which one you specify on the `fitted` parameter. But if you only have one set of hyperparameters and you are using `GridSearchCV` to just obtain different scoring methods, you can do this better with individual modules from `sklearn.metrics`.
- If you mean though that you want your classifier to be optimised based on a different method, then you should check the `criterion` parameter.